# Clear interval from within a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, clearinterval

I'm trying to clear an interval when the user hovers over an element and then start it up again when they hover off an element. I think this is a closure but I'm not sure, hopefully my code will make sense what I'm trying to do.

```
var rotatorInterval = function(elem){
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            var active = elem.find('.dot.active');
            if(active.is('.dot:last-of-type',elem)){
                elem.find('.dot').first().click();
            }else{
                active.next().click();
            }
        },6000);
        interval;
        return interval;
    };
if($('.rotator').length){
    $('.rotator').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        rotatorInterval(self);
        self.find('.slide, .dot').on('mouseenter',function(){
            console.log('hovered');
            clearInterval(interval);
        });
    });
}
```

I tried returning the interval from that closure but when I hovered it said interval (the name of the variable I returned) is not defined, so it's like it didn't return it or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to actually return the interval reference somewhere

```
var rotatorInterval = function (elem) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var active = elem.find('.dot.active');
        if (active.is('.dot:last-of-type', elem)) {
            elem.find('.dot').first().click();
        } else {
            active.next().click();
        }
    }, 6000);

    return interval;
};

if ($('.rotator').length) {
    $('.rotator').each(function () {
        var self = $(this);

        var return_interval = rotatorInterval(self);

        self.find('.slide, .dot').on('mouseenter', function () {

            clearInterval(return_interval);

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: check my code above I edited it correctly, I had hit undo a few times before copying the code when I posted. I'm returning it but it's still not working, it's saying it's not defined.

Comment: Also removing the call to the function and just returning it isn't working either

Comment: There's really no way for me to test that code, but did you return the interval exactly like above, into a variable etc

Comment: Sorry I didn't thoroughly read your code and was missing the variable expression you added in the each statement. It's working now.

Comment: You really don't have to post the answer again, just accept this one if it works ?